# Using usort in php with a class private function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

ok using usort with a function is not so complicated

This is what i had before in my linear code

```
function merchantSort($a,$b){
    return ....// stuff;
}

$array = array('..','..','..');
```

to sort i simply do

```
usort($array,"merchantSort");
```

Now we are upgrading the code and removing all global functions and putting them in their appropriate place. Now all the code is in a class and i can't figure out how to use the usort function to sort the array with the parameter that is an object method instead of a simple function

```
class ClassName {
   ...

   private function merchantSort($a,$b) {
       return ...// the sort
   }

   public function doSomeWork() {
   ...
       $array = $this->someThingThatReturnAnArray();
       usort($array,'$this->merchantSort'); // ??? this is the part i can't figure out
   ...

   }
}
```

The question is how do i call an object method inside the usort() function

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Make your sort function static:

```
private static function merchantSort($a,$b) {
       return ...// the sort
}
```

And use an array for the second parameter:

```
$array = $this->someThingThatReturnAnArray();
usort($array, array('ClassName','merchantSort'));
```

Comment: This is great! I'd also like to point out that the sort function doesn't have to be declared *implicitly* as a static method; as it still works without :)

Comment: @Jimbo - that makes sense, so the private function can use instantiation and class variables.  Yes, this is great!  Also see @deceze answer, where you can pass `$this` (neato).

Comment: If you make the function static (which you should), you can just write `usort($array, 'ClassName:merchantSort')`, can't you?

Comment: @MarcoW., I think there is a missing second ':' between ClassName and merchantSort. 
Also, if the function is being used inside the same class itself, I've tested it with `'self::merchantSort'` and it's working.

Answer (score 89):

1. open the manual page http://www.php.net/usort
2. see that the type for `$value_compare_func` is `callable`
3. click on the linked keyword to reach http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php
4. see that the syntax is `array($this, 'merchantSort')`

Answer (score 40):

You need to pass `$this` e.g.: `usort( $myArray, array( $this, 'mySort' ) );`

Full example:

```
class SimpleClass
{                       
    function getArray( $a ) {       
        usort( $a, array( $this, 'nameSort' ) ); // pass $this for scope
        return $a;
    }                 

    private function nameSort( $a, $b )
    {
        return strcmp( $a, $b );
    }              

}

$a = ['c','a','b']; 
$sc = new SimpleClass();
print_r( $sc->getArray( $a ) );
```

Answer (score 5):

In this example I am sorting by a field inside the array called AverageVote.

You could include the method inside the call, which means you no longer have the class scope problem, like this...

```
        usort($firstArray, function ($a, $b) {
           if ($a['AverageVote'] == $b['AverageVote']) {
               return 0;
           }

           return ($a['AverageVote'] < $b['AverageVote']) ? -1 : 1;
        });
```

Comment: That makes sense only if you are using this function only in this one sort. In many cases the same comparison is used in many places.

Comment: This was perfect for what I needed to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel (5.6) model class, I called it like this, both methods are public static, using php 7.2 on windows 64 bit.

```
public static function usortCalledFrom() 

public static function myFunction()
```

I did call in usortCalledFrom() like this

```
usort($array,"static::myFunction")
```

None of these were work

```
usort($array,"MyClass::myFunction")
usort($array, array("MyClass","myFunction")
```

Comment: `static::` instead of the class name is what I needed, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I hope it helps someone:

```
usort($array, [ClassName::class, "functionName"]);
```

Replace "ClassName" with the name of your PHP Class and "functionName" with the name of your private static function.

If everything occurs inside the own class this one works as well:

```
usort($array, [self::class, "functionName"]);
```

Replace "functionName" with the name of your private static function.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way would be to make an arrow function which calls your sort function like so:

```
uasort($array, fn($a, $b) => $this->mySortFunction($a, $b, $optionalAdditionalParam))
```

...

```
private function mySortFunction($a, $b) {
    return -1; // replace with sort logic
}
```

Comment: This seems sensible if you are extending the asked question.  However, the asker didn't mention anything about passing additional parameters to the sorting method.