# usort parameter issue

Tags: php, usort

I have the following code, which tries to sort an array of Products by it's creation date:

```
private function sortProductsByDate(Product $a, Product $b)
{
   if ($a->getCreated() == $b->getCreated()) {
      return 0;
   }
   return ($a->getCreated() < $b->getCreated()) ? -1 : 1;
}

/**
 * Get the most 4 recent items
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getMostRecentItems()
{
   $userMostRecentItems = array();
   $products = $this->getProducts();
   usort($products, "sortProductsByDate");

   foreach ($this->getProducts() as $product) {
      ladybug_dump($product->getCreated());
   }


   $mostRecentItems = $this->products;
   return $this->isLocked;
}
```

Why does this gives me this error:

```
Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

Ideas?

Comment: You're missing the `;` on the previous line.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski now it's a different error

Comment: Yep, you'll be in the wrong context for the callback. Did you [read the `usort()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to see the section on calling a class member function as its callback?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053994/using-usort-in-php-with-a-class-private-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `getProducts()` returns a `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` (most probably an `ArrayCollection`). Use

```
$products = $this->getProducts()->getValues();
```

You'll also want to use

```
usort($products, array($this, 'sortProductsByDate'));
```

and finally, use the `$products` array in your `foreach`

```
foreach ($products as $product)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is clear. It said that the first parameter should be array, but you pass object instead which means that `$this->getProducts();` returns objects instead of array.

Try this to see what is the type of variable products. I doubt you are returning a database resource instead of array here.

```
var_dump($products);
```