# PHP: How to usort within a class?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `usort` within a PHP class. The second parameter required is supposed to be a valid callback. How do I do this from within a class? This is not working:

```
usort($my_array, "$this->compare_function");
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053994/using-usort-in-php-with-a-class-private-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
usort ($my_array, array($this, 'compare_function');
```

Comment: Please use code formatting. And to make answers better, you can add a link to a reference page (such as http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) or a brief explanation or something to help others who didn't already have that info (which is why they're here).

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. I am on my phone at work and its a lot more difficult to do that. I will try to fix it later if I can

Comment: I always forget about mobile. No worries. Mere suggestions is all.

Comment: @zero: you can format code using four spaces before it. I've not tried the mobile app, but I imagine that would be quite easy to add.