# How to callback in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, callback

I have this code in:
App\Helpers;

```
class LowestLoadedServer {
    public static function getServer($video)
    {
        $pliki = $video->files()->with('server')->get();
        $aPliki = array();
        foreach($pliki as $plik)
        {
            $aPliki[] = $plik;
        }
        usort($aPliki, 'LowestLoadedServer::sortByLoadASC');
        return $aPliki[0]->server;
    }

    public static function sortByLoadASC($a, $b)
    {
        if($a->server->load > $b->server->load) return 1;
        if($a->server->load < $b->server->load) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and I my error:

> usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, class 'App/Helpers/LowestLoadedServer' not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using usort in php with a class private function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053994/using-usort-in-php-with-a-class-private-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 different ways on my mind..

The first one is the one you have tried, but you should  specify the full namespace of your class or simply use the `self` keyword:

```
usort($aPliki, "App\\Helpers\\LowestLoadedServer::sortByLoadASC");

usort($aPliki, "self::sortByLoadASC");
```

The second one is to pass an array with the class and the function:

```
usort($aPliki, ["App\\Helpers\\LowestLoadedServer", 'sortByLoadASC']);

usort($aPliki, ['self', 'sortByLoadASC']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```
class LowestLoadedServer {
public static function getServer($video,Closure $callback)
{
    $pliki = $video->files()->with('server')->get();
    $aPliki = array();
    foreach($pliki as $plik)
    {
        $aPliki[] = $plik;
    }
    usort($aPliki,$callback);
    return $aPliki[0]->server;
}

public static function sortByLoadASC($a, $b)
{
    if($a->server->load > $b->server->load) return 1;
    if($a->server->load < $b->server->load) return -1;
    return 0;
}
}
```

And pass your Callback function like : `self::sortByLoadASC` 
Without quotations.