# usort objects by object property using casting

Tags: php, object

I have an array of objects which have a property `id` I wish to sort by. This property contains the numbers as strings. I am trying to cast these strings to ints to sort them.

```
array(
    object(stdClass)#10717 (26) {
        ["id"]=>
            string(2) "12"
    },
    object(stdClass)#10718 (26) {
        ["id"]=>
            string(2) "13"
    }
    object(stdClass)#10719 (26) {
        ["id"]=>
            string(2) "8"
    }
 ...
```

My code is as such

```
class Test 
{
    public static function test( $array ) {
        usort( $array, 'callBackSort')

        return $array;
    }

    function callBackSort( $a, $b ) {
        $a = $a->id;
        $a = (int)$a;
        $b = $b->id;
        $b = (int)$b;

        if ( $a == $b ) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ( $a < $b ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

// In another file
$array = Test::test($array);
var_dump( $array );
```

However this is not working, the array is not sorted (no different from the original array). I am completely unfamiliar with usort.

**EDIT:** If I remove the callback function from the class and put it in the same file as `$array = Test::test($array);` Then it seems to work.

Comment: Works just fine when I test it without the `public statis function` part. **So you had better add that into the code you show in your question**

Comment: Thanks for testing @RiggsFolly I have added that information into my question

Comment: I assume that `public static function` is in a class, right?

Comment: And how do you pass the `$array` to that method/function. Is this just a scope issue????

Comment: It was a typo, I have updated the question

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What error or unexpected behavior or result are you getting?

Comment: I am still not sure what you are actually doing. Is `public static function test( $array ) {` in a class??? If so please show it as such!!!

Comment: I just updated the question to be more complete. I guess I stripped it back too much...

Comment: @RyanVincent but his Test::test() method returns the usorted array and he uses it appropriately

Comment: @gazareth, it did make sense before all the edits :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your usort() function is trying to call a non-static method called "callBackSort" from within a static context.

To keep your callBackSort function in the same file (class) as the "test" method, make it static and either public, protected or private depending on whether you will have use for it elsewhere, and call it by passing an array as the second argument to usort.

By the by, your callBackSort function is a little more complex than it needs to be. You don't need to cast the values to int to do comparisons.

```
class Test 
{
    public static function test( $array ) {

        //this will call a static method called "callBackSort" from class "Test" - equivalent to calling Test::callBackSort()
        usort( $array, array("Test", "callBackSort"));

        return $array;
    }

    public static function callBackSort( $a, $b ) {

        if ( $a->id == $b->id ) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ( $a->id < $b->id ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

See this answer for a similar case:
[Using usort in php with a class private function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053994/using-usort-in-php-with-a-class-private-function)

Comment: This was the issue exactly! I did not know you could have a callback as anything other than a procedural function. Works nicely now

Comment: This works in a whole bunch of callable situations, e.g. array_map. If you are working in a non-static context you can also do usort($array, array($this, "method")).