# How can I sort object on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5.3

My object array ($c) like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => chelsea.png
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => arsenal.png
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => mu.png
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => city.png
        )

)
```

I want to sort it by id

If in php normal I try like this :

```
function sort_by_id( $a, $b )
{ 
  if(  $a->id ==  $b->id ){ return 0 ; } 
  return ($a->id < $b->id) ? -1 : 1;
} 
usort($c,'sort_by_id');  
echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';
```

It works

But How can I implement it use laravel?

I try like this :

```
public function add($param)
{
    ...
    usort($c, $this->sortById()); 
    echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';die();
    ...
}

private function sortById($a, $b)
{ 
    if($a->id == $b->id) { 
        return 0 ; 
    } 
    return ($a->id < $b->id) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

It does not work

There exist error like this :

> Undefined property ...  $sortById ...

How can I solve it?

Comment: Although there are solutions provided for sorting an array with objects in it, I would suggest you to take a look, why you are getting such structure in the first place. Laravel has built in `toArray` methods for most cases, so you can convert objects to arrays on the calls.

Comment: [Using usort in php with a class private function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6053994/6521116)  https://eval.in/818360

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Laravel is a fantastic framework that did lots of work for you already.

First, you need to convert your array to a Collection:

```
$c = collect($c);
```

Now, For working with collections, you have a nice set of **[available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods)** you can work with. In your case, you need the **[sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby)**:

```
$sorted = $c->sortBy('id');
```

Alternatively, you can pass a callback:

```
$sorted = $c->sortBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->id;
});
```

Both of these will return a Collection object. If you want to get an Array back instead, use `all()` or `toArray()` on your result:

```
$c = $c->all();

// or

$c = $c->toArray();
```

Comment: It works. But the result : `Array
(
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => city.png
        )

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => chelsea.png
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => arsenal.png
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => mu.png
        )
)`. The index : 3 -> 0 -> 1 ->2. I want the index also change. Should like this : 0->1->2->3

Comment: @TrendingNews Use `values()` method on the result, like this: `$c = $c->values()->toArray();` Read about the values() method [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-values).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public function add($param)
{
    ...
    usort($c, function($a, $b){
        if($a->id == $b->id) { 
        return 0 ; 
    } 
    return ($a->id < $b->id) ? -1 : 1;
    }); 
    echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';die();
    ...
}
```

You don't need to use different `sortById` method

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure php way:

In your first case you are trying to pass a *procedural function* as a callback to your `usort` function.

When you want to pass a *method* from a class as a callback you need to pass it as follows:

```
usort($c, [$this, 'sortById']);
```

Checkout the third example from the [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) man page.

Note that, you will using the `$this` variable as long as you are within the class. If you want to use the context of another class for example, you will need to pass the instance as follows:

```
$object = new someClass;
usort($c, [$object, 'sortById']);
```

Also in case if you need to pass a static method you can simply pass it as follows:

```
usort($c, ['someClass', 'sortById']);
```